# How can I create an abstract sea/wave effect in a free vector package?

Tags: vector, inkscape, gradient, illustration

I'm looking to create a vector (ideally) illustration with an abstract sea, much like this (not the dolphins or sun):

[image: Abstract sea]

How can I go about this using free tools such as Inkscape?

Comment: You can also check the collections on the [open clipart](http://openclipart.org/collections) for a viable starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4sfmzJ-2ps) on how to create wave-like vector shapes in Inkscape. Then the fill you want are shades of blue gradients that goes from blue to transparent with a stroke around the lighter shades of blue.